# realizar consulta con checkbox y filtro de fecha javascript php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

tengo un script de `js` que hace una consulta a una base de datos `mysql` con `php`,actualmente solo hago un filtro en la consulta por fecha y lo muestro en una tabla con datatables y funciona perfecto,pero ahora me solicitaron que ademas de hacer el filtro de fecha,tambien pueda filtrar por los campos(transmisores) de la base de datos,estoy intentando hacerlo con checkbox,pero la verdad no entiendo como hacerlo,ya que puede haber momentos en los que se seleccionen 3 o 4 o cualquier numero de checkbox,alguien podria guiarme o darme una ayuda sobre como hacer esto?? gracias por la ayuda

fragmento codigo html

`

```
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T1'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 1</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T2'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 2</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T3'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 3</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T4'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 4</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T5'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 5</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T6'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 6</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T7'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 7</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T8'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 8</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T9'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 9</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T10'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 10</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T11'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 11</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T12'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 12</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T13'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 13</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T14'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 14</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T15'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 15</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T16'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 16</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T17'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 17</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T18'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 18</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T19'/><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 19</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox"  name='checkbox[]' value='T20'/></td><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 20</label></li>
                    <li><input type='checkbox'  name='checkbox[]' value='T21'/></td><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 21</label></li>
                    <li><input type='checkbox'  name='checkbox[]' value='T22'/></td><label for="text1">TRANSMISOR 22</label></li>
`
```

framento de codigo js

`

```
$(document).on('submit', '#datos', function(event) {
        $('#loading').show();
        event.preventDefault();
        var desde = $("#desde").val();
        var hasta = $("#hasta").val();
        var hr_inicio = $("#hr_inicio").val();
        var hr_fin = $("#hr_fin").val();
        var checkbox = $("#checkbox").val();
               
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'php/mostrar.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:  { 'desde': desde, 'hasta': hasta,'hr_inicio': hr_inicio ,'hr_fin':hr_fin,'checkbox':checkbox } ,
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response)
                        $('#loading').hide();
                        $('#tabla').show();
                        $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                }); 

            });
            $('#example').DataTable({
                "ajax": 'php/resultados_adquiridos.json',
                "columns": [
                    //{ "data": "ID" },
                    { "data": "T1" },
                    { "data": "T2" },
                    { "data": "T3" },
                    { "data": "T4" },
                    { "data": "T5" },
                    { "data": "T6" },
                    { "data": "T7" },
                    { "data": "T8" },
                    { "data": "T9" },
                    { "data": "T10" },
                    { "data": "T11" },
                    { "data": "T12" },
                    { "data": "T13" },
                    { "data": "T14" },
                    { "data": "T15" },
                    { "data": "T16" },
                    { "data": "T17" },
                    { "data": "T18" },
                    { "data": "T19" },
                    { "data": "T20" },
                    { "data": "T21" },
                    { "data": "T22" },
                    { "data": "FECHA" },
                ],
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'excel',
                        filename:  "registros "+day+ "-"+ month+ "-" +year                     },'copy','pdf'
                    
                    
                ]
            });
            
        });
```

codigo php)mostrar.php

`

```
<?php

$inc = include("con_db.php");
    if (isset($_POST['desde'] ) and isset($_POST['hasta'] ) and isset($_POST['hr_inicio'] ) and isset($_POST['hr_fin'] )) {

        $inicio = $_POST['desde'];
        $fin= $_POST['hasta'];
        $hr_inicio= $_POST['hr_inicio'];
        $hr_fin= $_POST['hr_fin'];
        $checkboxes=$_POST['checkbox'];
        $transmisores=implode('|', $checkboxes);

        $consulta="SELECT * FROM datos_de_temperatura WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '$inicio $hr_inicio'AND '$fin $hr_fin' AND TRANSMISOR REGEXP '".$transmisores."'";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
        $json_array=array();
        //$enable_json=0;
        if ($resultado){
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
            {
                $id=$row['ID'];
                $t1=$row['T1'];
                $t2=$row['T2'];
                $t3=$row['T3'];
                $t4=$row['T4'];
                $t5=$row['T5'];
                $t6=$row['T6'];
                $t7=$row['T7'];
                $t8=$row['T8'];
                $t9=$row['T9'];
                $t10=$row['T10'];
                $t11=$row['T11'];
                $t12=$row['T12'];
                $t13=$row['T13'];
                $t14=$row['T14'];
                $t15=$row['T15'];
                $t16=$row['T16'];
                $t17=$row['T17'];
                $t18=$row['T18'];
                $t19=$row['T19'];
                $t20=$row['T20'];
                $t21=$row['T21'];
                $t22=$row['T22'];
                $fecha=$row['FECHA'];
                $json_array[] =  ['ID'=> $id, 'T1'=> $t1,'T2'=> $t2,'T3'=> $t3,'T4'=> $t4,'T5'=> $t5,'T6'=> $t6,'T7'=> $t7,'T8'=> $t8,'T9'=> $t9,'T10'=> $t10,'T11'=> $t11,'T12'=> $t12,'T13'=> $t13,'T14'=> $t14,'T15'=> $t15,'T16'=> $t16,'T17'=> $t17,'T18'=> $t18,'T19'=> $t19,'T20'=> $t20,'T21'=> $t21,'T22'=> $t22, 'FECHA'=> $fecha ];  
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás tratando de obtener los *checkboxes* por ID `var checkbox = $("#checkbox").val();` pero no tienen ID y, en todo caso, solo te devolvería el primero.

Se pueden obtener por nombre `$('[name^="checkbox"]')` y, de preferencia, solo los que están marcados agregando `:checked`. Esto te devuelve una colección que se debe recorrer con `.map()` para crear un arreglo de valores y `.get()` para devolverlos.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#datos', function(event) {
    $('#loading').show();
    event.preventDefault();
    var desde = $("#desde").val();
    var hasta = $("#hasta").val();
    var hr_inicio = $("#hr_inicio").val();
    var hr_fin = $("#hr_fin").val();
    // Obtener checkboxes por nombre y solo los que están marcados
    var checkbox = $('[name^="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
           
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/mostrar.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'desde': desde,
            'hasta': hasta,
            'hr_inicio': hr_inicio,
            'hr_fin':hr_fin,
            'checkbox':checkbox
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#tabla').show();
            $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    }); 
});
```

En PHP vas a poder recibir el arreglo de *checkboxes* pero solo lo agregas a la consulta si se seleccionó alguno y usando *IN*, en lugar de _REGEXP

```
    $inicio = $_POST['desde'];
    $fin = $_POST['hasta'];
    $hr_inicio = $_POST['hr_inicio'];
    $hr_fin = $_POST['hr_fin'];
    // Si no se seleccionó alguno, no vas a tener la variable en $_POST
    // Se usa asignación ternaria
    $checkboxes = (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) ? $_POST['checkbox'] : [];

    // Quedará vacío si no se marcó ningún checkbox
    $transmisores = '';
    if(count($checkboxes) == 1) {
        // Solo se seleccionó uno, no es necesario usar IN
        $transmisores = ' AND transmisor = ' . $checkboxes[0];
    } elseif(count($checkboxes) > 1) {
        // Operador IN, con valores entre paréntesis y separados por coma
        $transmisores = ' AND transmisor IN (' . implode(', ', $checkboxes) . ')';
    }

    $consulta="SELECT * FROM datos_de_temperatura WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '$inicio $hr_inicio' AND '$fin $hr_fin' $tansmisores";
```