# SQL - PHP, Como hacer una devolución distinta si cadena llega vacía para sentencia IN

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Buen dia, estoy teniendo un problema en la siguiente consulta, seria de gran ayuda si alguien se topo con esto, estoy trabajandop con php y sqlserver.
La consulta es la siguiente:

-php-

```
$RUBROS = isset($_POST['rubro_trabajo']) ? $_POST['rubro_trabajo'] : '';
$RUBROS_2 =  implode("','", (array)$RUBROS);

function get_user_trabajo($RUBROS_2) { 
    $sql = "SELECT ANTECEDENTE_LABORAL.EXPERIENCIA_A, ANTECEDENTE_LABORAL.EXPERIENCIA_M, ANTECEDENTE_LABORAL.FK_ID_RUBRO, ANTECEDENTE_LABORAL.FK_ID_POSTULANTE, DATOS_EXTRAS.PASANTIA, DATOS_EXTRAS.HOMEOFFICE, DATOS_EXTRAS.TRABAJO_AQUI
            FROM ANTECEDENTE_LABORAL INNER JOIN
                DATOS_EXTRAS ON ANTECEDENTE_LABORAL.FK_ID_POSTULANTE = DATOS_EXTRAS.FK_ID_USUARIO
            WHERE (FK_ID_RUBRO IN  ('$RUBROS_2') 
--ACÁ QUIERO QUE SI $RUBROS_2 o directamente RUBROS esta vacio 'evite' el where
            ";  

    $conn = conectarBD();
    $arreglo = array($RUBROS_2);
    $resultado = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $arreglo);
    $json = array();
    if ($resultado === false) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    while ($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($json, $fila);
    }

    return $jsonstring = json_encode($json); 
}
```

Comment: Si el array llega vacío, no añadas el where...

Comment: Y cómo "llegan los números al where"?

Comment: Gracias por contestar, entiendo que si quito el where funciona. Pero necesito tener la consulta como para que devuelva los registros del where in si llega con datos, o que devuelva todo si llega sin datos. No tengo mucha experiencia en sql

Comment: Los "numeros al where llegan" por php

Comment: puedes agregar un `OR` con tu misma lógica actual, algo como: `OR @Parametros IS NULL` (o algún equivalente)

Comment: Esa consulta es un **SP** o la generas en **php**???

Comment: @DavElsanto la genero mediante php

Comment: Si el PHP arma la consulta, ponlo en tu pregunta y ajustarlo es fácil. Si es un SP, pon el código del SP completo y ajustarlo es fácil. No pongas a adivinar a los que quieren responder. Edita tu pregunta

Comment: @Alfabravo comprendo, editando, gracias

Comment: Edite un poco la pregunta, quizás estaba mal orientada. Gracias por los comentarios

Comment: es como te decías, puedes agregar algo como: `OR LEN($RUBROS_2) = 0` (y ojo con como estás haciendo esto, tiene riesgos de [SQL injection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-ver15&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5002315))

Comment: te recomiendo que hagas lo siguiente: agrega un if donde vas a revisar si tu variable **RUBROS** o **RUBROS_2** tiene esos datos. Ahora bien a tu otra variable **sql** concatenas el **where** únicamente cuando cumpla tus condiciones.

Comment: @Lamak, gracias, intentare, pero creo que me voy a encaminar mas por la respuesta de Dav

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/385031/realizar-consulta-con-checkbox-y-filtro-de-fecha-javascript-php/385050#385050) seguro te sirve de guía.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$where = !empty($RUBROS_2) ? " WHERE (FK_ID_RUBRO IN  ('$RUBROS_2') " : '';
$sql   = "SELECT ANTECEDENTE_LABORAL.EXPERIENCIA_A, ANTECEDENTE_LABORAL.EXPERIENCIA_M, ANTECEDENTE_LABORAL.FK_ID_RUBRO, ANTECEDENTE_LABORAL.FK_ID_POSTULANTE, DATOS_EXTRAS.PASANTIA, DATOS_EXTRAS.HOMEOFFICE, DATOS_EXTRAS.TRABAJO_AQUI
        FROM ANTECEDENTE_LABORAL INNER JOIN
            DATOS_EXTRAS ON ANTECEDENTE_LABORAL.FK_ID_POSTULANTE = DATOS_EXTRAS.FK_ID_USUARIO
        $where";
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por el valioso tiempo, funciona cumple con el objetivo